# How to add full html code into an PHP array and echo the array with array_rand function

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am trying to print random slections from an array. However array contains full html and it causes problems, it does not echo the whole html. It just displays the texts within the HTML. I have tried singles quotes but also did not work.

Here is the the thing what i have done;

```
$items = Array('<div class="custom-top-tags">
<div class="sm-top-tags-title">Öne Çıkanlar:</div>
<div class="sm-top-tags-keywords">
<ul class="sm-top-tags-keywords-list">
<li><a href="makina-grubu?keyword=Matkap">Matkaplar</a></li>
<li><a href="eldiven-grubu">İş Eldivenleri</a></li>
<li><a href="shop?keyword=Karıştırıcı">Mikser & Karıştırıcı</a></li>
<li><a href="shop?keyword=Silikon">Silikon</a></li>
<li><a href="shop?keyword=Tangit">Tangitt</a></li>
<li><a href="shop?keyword=Lokma+Takımı">Lokma Takımı</a></li>
<li><a href="shop?keyword=Plastik+Boru+Makası">Plastik Boru Makası</a></li>
<li><a href="shop?keyword=El+Arabası">El Arabası</a></li>
<li><a href="shop?keyword=Vana">Vanalar</a></li>
<li><a href="boya-grubu">Boya</a></li>
<li><a href="makina-grubu?keyword=Kompresör">Kompresör</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>',
'<div class="custom-top-tags">
<div class="sm-top-tags-title">Öne Çıkanlar:</div>
<div class="sm-top-tags-keywords">
<ul class="sm-top-tags-keywords-list">
<li><a href="makina-grubu?keyword=Matkap">Matkaplar</a></li>
<li><a href="eldiven-grubu">İş Eldivenleri</a></li>
<li><a href="shop?keyword=Karıştırıcı">Mikser & Karıştırıcı</a></li>
<li><a href="shop?keyword=Silikon">Silikon</a></li>
<li><a href="shop?keyword=Tangit">Tangitt</a></li>
<li><a href="shop?keyword=Lokma+Takımı">Lokma Takımı</a></li>
<li><a href="shop?keyword=Plastik+Boru+Makası">Plastik Boru Makası</a></li>
<li><a href="shop?keyword=El+Arabası">El Arabası</a></li>
<li><a href="shop?keyword=Vana">Vanalar</a></li>
<li><a href="boya-grubu">Boya</a></li>
<li><a href="makina-grubu?keyword=Kompresör">Kompresör</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>');


echo $items[array_rand($items)];
```

And my expectaion is displaying randomly selected HTML code.

**Meaning, i need to choose different links randomly from a list and i need to display them in html with codes as seen below.**

```
<div class="custom-top-tags">
    <div class="sm-top-tags-title">Öne Çıkanlar:</div>
    <div class="sm-top-tags-keywords">
    <ul class="sm-top-tags-keywords-list">
    <li><a href="makina-grubu?keyword=Matkap">Matkaplar</a></li>
    <li><a href="eldiven-grubu">İş Eldivenleri</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop?keyword=Karıştırıcı">Mikser & Karıştırıcı</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop?keyword=Silikon">Silikon</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop?keyword=Tangit">Tangitt</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop?keyword=Lokma+Takımı">Lokma Takımı</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop?keyword=Plastik+Boru+Makası">Plastik Boru Makası</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop?keyword=El+Arabası">El Arabası</a></li>
    <li><a href="shop?keyword=Vana">Vanalar</a></li>
    <li><a href="boya-grubu">Boya</a></li>
    <li><a href="makina-grubu?keyword=Kompresör">Kompresör</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Waiting for the suggestions and helps.

Comment: *However array contains full html and it causes problems* - what problems?

Comment: it cannot fully print the html content, it just displays Text

Comment: This array contains only one entry!

Comment: I know that copied mistakenly the same content

Answer (score 1):

The line breaks in you code won't work...
I would suggest to split the code into a temp variable and then array allocation
And use the proper multi lkne syntax

1st of all for styling purposes, and also to prevent this error

You should use $tempvar and the code I wrote for each array insertion

```
$items  = array();
$tempvar = <<<TEMP
    <div class="custom-top-tags">
 <div class="sm-top-tags-title">Öne Çıkanlar:</div> 
<div class="sm-top-tags-keywords">
 <ul class="sm-top-tags-keywords-list"> <li><a href="makina-grubu?keyword=Matkap">Matkaplar</a></li> <li><a href="eldiven-grubu">İş Eldivenleri</a></li> 
<li><a href="shop?keyword=Karıştırıcı">Mikser & Karıştırıcı</a></li> 
<li><a href="shop?keyword=Silikon">Silikon</a></li> 
<li><a href="shop?keyword=Tangit">Tangitt</a></li> <li><a href="shop?keyword=Lokma+Takımı">Lokma Takımı</a></li> 
<li><a href="shop?keyword=Plastik+Boru+Makası">Plastik Boru Makası</a></li>
 <li><a href="shop?keyword=El+Arabası">El Arabası</a></li> <li><a href="shop?keyword=Vana">Vanalar</a></li> 
<li><a href="boya-grubu">Boya</a></li> <li><a href="makina-grubu?keyword=Kompresör">Kompresör</a></li> </ul> </div> </div>
TEMP;

    $items[] = $tempvar;

    ...
```

Comment: Thank you but how can i randomly select them? should i create two differen tempvar?

Comment: no no, I used the 3 dots to save the reptitiveness of the solution... you should use tempvar 3 times and use array_rand as you did

Comment: Oohh ok, i will try it now

Comment: I could not make it work, would you help me with that?

Comment: @orko sure, can you elaborate on what exactly broke? try to print the 1st tempvar right after the allocation. what do you get?

Comment: It throws a syntax error, i think i am doing something wrong

Comment: TEMP; that closes the text, cant be tabbed and muat be in column 1 on the line it is in

Comment: i just copied the code you had written and add array_rand

Comment: @orko break the code to pieces or use a debug tool, to issolate the problem... then I can help more

Comment: Could not make, i am a newbie :(

Answer (score 0):

that is one possible solution

```
echo htmlspecialchars($items[array_rand($items)]);
```

Comment: for custom output echo "<pre>".htmlspecialchars($items[array_rand($items)])."</pre>";